# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list create a script that concatenates values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to create a script that concatenates values in files into columns. But unfortunately I get an error: **"TypeError: can only concatenate list (not" str ") to list"**

What am I doing wrong?

```
import re
inputList = []
for file in ['text1.txt','text2.txt']:
    with open(file,'r') as infile:
        k = 0
        for line in infile:
            i = 0
            if i < len(inputList) and k:
                inputList[i].extend(re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9,]+', '', line).split(","))
            else :
                inputList.append(re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9,]+', '', line).split(","))
            i += 1
        k = 1
print(inputList)
with open('text3','w') as outfile:
    for line in inputList:
        outfile.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: I guess, error is not because of the current code. Can you specify which line gives an error? It will be specified in your error message.

Comment: @Rahul Unfortunately, the error occurs on line 17.  " Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\script.py", line 17, in <module>
    outfile.write(line + '\n')
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"

Comment: Got it. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can not concatenate list with string.

In your code `line` is `list` and you are trying to concatenate it with `'\n'` a `str`. I don't know what You are trying to acomplish here but for your code to work you can do something like `outfile.write('f{line}\n')`.

I would recommend using built-in `json` module instead. Json works best with `list` or `dict` containg `str` data.

```
import json
with open('text3','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(inputList, outfile)
```

Comment: I put this in the code you recommended. Everything was saved to a file, but as a result, all values were saved in one line. And I need two columns and how the table according to the list.

Comment: If you can include input and expected output output, will be helpful